# How to properly comment JavaScript function which belongs to an object in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm, jsdoc

I have a simple JavaScript dependency loader library. define function defines the class into the classes object with the given name and require function make sure that the specified code runs when the dependency met.

As `MyClass` and `MyClass2` registered into the classes object, I need to access them with `classes.MyClass` and `classes.MyClass2`. I would like to make comment to MyClass and MyClass2 to tell PhpStorm where to look for these. Currently I get "Unresolved type MyClass"

[image: PhpStorm]

Is there I way to properly comment such situation with JSDoc?

```js
var classes = {},
    _loaded = {};

function define(name, callback) {
    classes[name] = callback(jQuery);
    if (typeof _loaded[name] === 'undefined') {
        _loaded[name] = jQuery.Deferred();
    }

    _loaded[name].resolve();
}

function require(name, callback) {
    if (typeof _loaded[name] === 'undefined') {
        _loaded[name] = jQuery.Deferred();
    }

    _loaded[name].done(callback);
}


define('MyClass', function($) {
    function MyClass() {}

    MyClass.prototype.hello = function() {
        $('body').html('Hello')
    };

    return MyClass;
});

setTimeout(function() {
    define('MyClass2', function($) {
        function MyClass2() {}

        MyClass2.prototype.hello = function() {
            $('body').html('Hello MyClass2')
        };

        return MyClass2;
    });
}, 4000);


require('MyClass', function() {
    var a = new classes.MyClass();
    a.hello();
});

require('MyClass2', function() {
    var b = new classes.MyClass2();
    b.hello();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @exports classes.MyClass seems to solve this issue, but any related suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@memberOf` seems to do the thing:

```
define('MyClass', function($) {
  /**
   *
   * @memberOf classes
   */
  function MyClass() {}

    MyClass.prototype.hello = function() {
        $('body').html('Hello')
    };

    return MyClass;
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, and what do you think which is the better \@memberOf classes or \@exports classes.MyClass

Comment: `@exports` is normally used for documenting modules (http://usejsdoc.org/tags-exports.html)... anyway, it's fine if it works for you:)

Comment: I'm just looking for the right solution to use and it seems like you have more experience than me so probably `@memberOf` is the way to go :)